# Tableau rotating data table

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset that looks like this in Tableau.

```
Name    Subject      Grade
Mina    Math         28
        English      92
        Science      10
Bill    Math         19
        English      10
        Science      38
Kay     Math         39
        English      92
        Science      83
```

I need the data to look like this

```
Name Math English Science 
Mina 28   92      10
Bill 19   10      38
Kay  39   92      83
```

How can I do this in Tableau? I am assuming I need to create a calculated field. Just not sure how to approach this as I am a beginner.

Comment: This called a pivot. Tableau can do it easily. Read the online help, and search for pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Alex Blakemore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441979/alex-blakemore) suggested, you could pivot your entire dataset in the data source page itself, but I am assuming the first view you have is a Worksheet with Name, Subject, Grade fields in columns of the worksheet, and you would like to present your data as in the second view without modifying your data source.

It's possible by creating three calculated fields:

```
Math: 
IF [Subject] = "Math" THEN [Grade] END

English: 
IF [Subject] = "English" THEN [Grade] END

Science:
IF [Subject] = "Science" THEN [Grade] END
```

Now try dragging Name, Math, English and Science fields into the columns of the Tableau Worksheet and you should be able to get what you need without actually pivoting your data source itself. Hope this helps!